# Why oracle thinks this query is malformed?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm sending the following sql to oracle db, and getting `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`.

```
SELECT "LOGS"."ID", 
   "LOGS"."USER_ID", 
   "LOGS"."TIMESTAMP", 
   "LOGS"."SESSION_ID"        
FROM "LOGS"
INNER JOIN "USERS" ON ("LOGS"."USER_ID" = "USERS"."USER_ID") 
WHERE ("USERS"."USERNAME" IS NOT NULL 
  AND "LOGS"."TIMESTAMP" <= TO_TIMESTAMP(2013-03-26 23:59:59, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
  AND "LOGS"."TIMESTAMP" >= TO_TIMESTAMP(2013-03-26 00:00:00, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') )
```

What can be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your timestamp literal is malformed. You forgot the quotes. Write

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-03-26 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

Or even (since you're using SQL standard timestamp literal formats)

```
TIMESTAMP '2013-03-26 23:59:59'
```

Instead of

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(2013-03-26 23:59:59, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```